# How do I declare the version of Lucene.Net 3.0.3

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am beginning to learn Lucene.Net and was wondering how you declare the version number?

Here is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30); //Version.Lucene_30 is where the problem lies.
```

I have also tried:

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version);
```

but get the same result.

Comment: What doesn't work? Describe you problem clearly. Also, your second attempt doesn't make sense, as you are supplying an enum class as the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare the version of Lucene.Net you can create a variable:

```
var version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30;
```

After this just add the variable into the StandardAnalyzer argument:

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(version);
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but you conclusion is wrong; you do not need to declare the version of Lucene.Net as a variable, but you _do_ need to include the namespace of the class. If you had a simple `using Lucene.Net.Util.Version;` statement your first attempt in the question would have worked.

Comment: I tried to add the namespace you suggested, it did not work.

Comment: Again "did not work" is too vague; what specifically failed and what error messages did it give you?

Comment: Specifically, there are two errors.  The first says "C#: Expected a namespace".  The second says "This using directive is not required."  The program works fine now, that's why I said your method "did not work."